# Loop and return all bitwise values in Long

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

To set bits, you use the OR operator. You can then use the AND operator to see which bits have been set:

```
long values = 0;

// Set bits
values |= (1L << 10);
values |= (1L << 45);
values |= (1L << 5600);

// Check if values are set
System.out.println(hasValue(values, 45));   // Returns true
System.out.println(hasValue(values, 55));   // Returns false
System.out.println(hasValue(values, 5600)); // Returns true

public static boolean hasValue(long data, int value)
{
    return (((data >> value) & 1L) > 0);
}
```

Is it possible to loop through `values` and return each of the values originally set with the OR operator? The result printing:

```
Found value: 10
Found value: 45
Found value: 5600
```

**Edit**: Altered example to include larger numbers.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Trying to call `hasValue(values, 45)` once with every number from 0 to 63 instead of just `45`?

Comment: I am stuck trying to find unknown values. I want to be told that `45` or `5600` exists within `values` without specifying those numbers.

Comment: A `long` can only store 64 bits, so adding `1L<<5600` will wrap around and be the same as `1L<<32` (because 5600 ≡ 32 mod 64). Do you instead want to use a data type that can keep track of thousands of bits without wrapping?

Comment: @thatotherguy that is making sense now. an alternate data type is needed

Comment: For a dense set you can use a `BitSet`. For a sparse set you can use a `HashSet<Integer>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand question correctly. You just need to shift values by 1, and check youngest bit by AND 1 like that:

```
class Main {  
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        long v = 0;
        v |= (1L << 10);
        v |= (1L << 45);
        v |= (1L << 56);
        int i = 0;
        while(v != 0) {
            if((v & 1L) == 1) {
                 System.out.println("Found value: " + i);
            }
            v = v >>> 1;
            i++;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is on the mark! I'm curious about  `v = v >>> 1` vs using `v = v >> 1`. Would there be a difference between the logical and arithmetic shifts?

Comment: @dinorider in right arithmetic shift, right bit fills by sign of number, it means that when you make shift on negative number right bit will be filled by 1, because of sign. In logical shift it always fills by zero.

Answer (score 2):

You could use your function inside of a loop from 0 to 64 to find everything like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    if (hasValue(values, i))
        System.out.println(“Found value: “ + i);
}
```

But I think there’s a better way. It’s destructive to the variable so if you want to save it for later do it before the loop but here it is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64 && values != 0; i++) {
    if (values % 2 == 1)
        System.out.println(“Found value: “ + i);
    values = values >> 1;
}
```

The big advantage is to shift one bit at a time and not i bits every time needed.

Comment: I think your optimized version should be `values % 2 == 1`, but it's working! Is this the same operation as iggi's solution of `(v & 1L) == 1`?

Comment: Yes you right I didn’t notice as I’m used to write equals 0. And essentially it’s the same but that’s just my preference.

Answer (score 0):

Java `long` has 64 bits.

So you could use 8 bits and store a maximum of 8 integers whose value is between 0 and 255 (unsigned).

You will need to use shift and then store.

So first unsigned byte will be 0-7 bits, second would be 8-15, third being 16-23 and so on.

But not otherwise.